# Mysql date("") with EST timezone?

Tags: php, mysql

So I went into my.ini and added

```
default-time-zone="-5:00"
```

Under the [mysqld] reset xmapp and when I add a person to my database it is still inserting into the database for date as 2/14/23 04:12:00? I should be set to EST since I put -5:00

This is what is on my php side not sure if I need to add a timezone some where here also or not.

```
, "date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
```

I haven't tried anything other than add the default-time-zone in my.ini
Anyone help with this since everything I looked up on google says to edit that file and it should work.

What I want it to do though is when it inserts the new person I would like it to do it for EST.

This would be what my code looks like

```
$stmt = $pdo->prpare("INSERT INTO `table`(`name`,`branch`,`startDate`) VALUES ( :name, :branch, :date) ");
$stmt->execute(["name" => $_POST["name'], "branch" => $_POST["branch"], "date" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") , ]);
```

Comment: Does `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` give you the correct datetime? Why not use `now()` and have the DB set with correct timezone setting. Also, if in US you should use a timezone setting that accounts for daylight savings time. This wont be correct when swaps to EDT.

Comment: I never looked into `now()` I always used `date()` so I am unsure if it gives the correct one. Does the `now()` post the persons current timezone or what is set in my.ini?

Comment: Nothing you are currently using takes the user's current time. PHP's `date` takes the server's time. The mysql `now()` uses the database system's current time. So either use `now()` and set the database system's timezone, or use PHP `date` and set the PHP timezone... or use UTC everywhere and just run calculations for displaying data in appropriate timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this, by saying to add

`date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`
Which worked. Not sure what happen to their answer, but that was my solution!